# A question regarding connectedness

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, quotient-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be connected spaces and $\ f: (X,\mathcal{T}_X) \rightarrow (Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$, $\ \ $ $g: (Y,\mathcal{T}_Y) \rightarrow (Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$ be continuous. Construct a quotient space $(X\sqcup Y)/_{\sim}$ by $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=g(y)$.

Show that if $f$ or $g$ is surjective, then $(X\sqcup Y)/_{\sim}$ is connected.

My idea runs as follows:

Assume $f$ is surjective first, and I have a feeling that $(X\sqcup Y)/_{\sim}$ should be homeomorphic to $Z$. Once a homeomorphism, or simply a continuous bijection is defined, then the result is proved.

Define the mapping $$\phi: Z \rightarrow (X\sqcup Y)/_{\sim} $$ by $\phi(z)=[x]$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of x such that $f(x)=z$.

It's easy to check that $\phi$ is a well-defined bijective map. But I have no idea how to show the continuity. When I tried to show the pre-image of an open set in the quotient space is open, I noticed that I don't have much information on the open sets in $Z$. So I doubt whether my attempt works.

Any suggestions? Is there any other ways to prove it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $X \sqcup Z$ when you say $X \sqcup Y$?

Comment: I just spot one typo, g should be a function defined on Y.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter there was a typo at first, I really meant the disjoint union of X and Y, but not Z.

Comment: Let $\pi \colon X \sqcup Y \to (X \sqcup Y)/{\sim}$ be the projection. Suppose you have disjoint open sets $U,V$ with $U\cup V = (X\sqcup Y)/{\sim}$, and say $U\neq \varnothing$. What can you say about $\pi^{-1}(U) \cap X$ and $\pi^{-1}(U)\cap Y$? Similarly for $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f \colon X \to Z$ is onto. Let $i \colon X \to X \sqcup Y$ be the inclusion and $\pi \colon X \sqcup Y \to (X \sqcup Y)/_\sim$ the quotient map. Since $f$ is onto, the composition $\pi \circ i \colon X \to (X \sqcup Y)/_\sim$ is also onto. Hence $(X \sqcup Y)/_\sim$ is connected, as it is a continuous image of a connected space.